# Launch third party app from Service

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, service

I need to launch an activity from a service. I tried using:

```
public void openApplication(String packageName){
      Intent intent = new Intent(packageName);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      this.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**But i get this error:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime(8563):android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.encrypted flg=0x10000000 }
04-30 11:55:07.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8563):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1765)
04-30 11:55:07.507: E/AndroidRuntime(8563):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1485)
```

Any idea?

Comment: The `Intent` constructor you are using takes an action string. It does not take a package name. Apparently, there is no activity on your device that happens to have its package name as an action string. You need to use an `Intent` that identifies an activity that exists. Ask the developer of the third-party app what `Intent` they suggest using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code instead. You need to get a launch `Intent` for the package:

```
public void openApplication(String packageName) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! It works perfectly! Can i give you some point or something? I'm new here i don't know much about stackoverflow. But if i can, let me know! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You've created an `Intent` with a certain 'action'. Find the correct action String that's handled by the desired application's IntentFilter. The packageName is **not the same** as the action.

If multiple applications should have the same action defined in an IntentFilter, the system will popup an IntentChooser where all these applications are shown in.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering. Maybe i had to add that the application i want to launch is a 3rd party application and it's not created by me. Does it change change something?